# DAYNAME(NOW())) no responde a variable

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buenas tardes compañeros, el objetivo de esta consulta es insertar los datos bajo 3 condiciones las cuales las mando a llamar con variables

A continuación les muestro el archivo donde realizo el input del primero campo

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Llenar un Combobox/Select con registros de una Tabla</title>
<link href="contactos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<form class="" action="ingresarasistencia.php" method="POST">


  <label for="idea">ID</label>
  <input type="text"  id="ID" name="ID" maxlength="255" placeholder="Digite nombre" oninput="Validar" >

   <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="Enviar">


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

este siguiente es donde proceso los datos y en el cual funciona todo correctamente pero cuando quiero condicionar

```html
<?php
 //conectamos Con el servidor
$conexion=@mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
 //verificamos la conexion
 if(!$conexion){
  echo"No Se Pudo Conectar Con El Servidor";
 }else{

  $base=mysql_select_db('gym');
  if(!$base){
   echo"No Se Encontro La Base De Datos";
  }
 }
 //recuperar las variables
$ID=$_POST['ID'];

$dia1 = "select dia1 from pagosclientes where idCliente LIKE '%$ID%' AND curdate() < final ";
$dia2 = "select dia2 from pagosclientes where idCliente LIKE '%$ID%' AND curdate() < final ";
$dia3 = "select dia3 from pagosclientes where idCliente LIKE '%$ID%'  AND curdate() < final ";
$dia4 = "select dia4 from pagosclientes where idCliente LIKE '%$ID%' AND curdate() < final ";
$dia5 = "select dia5 from pagosclientes where idCliente = '%$ID%' AND curdate() < final ";
$dia6 = "select dia6 from pagosclientes where idCliente LIKE '%$ID%' AND curdate() < final ";
$dia7 = "select dia7 from pagosclientes where idCliente LIKE '%$ID%' AND curdate() < final ";

$ejecutar1=mysql_query($dia1);
$ejecutar2=mysql_query($dia2);
$ejecutar3=mysql_query($dia3);
$ejecutar4=mysql_query($dia4);
$ejecutar5=mysql_query($dia5);
$ejecutar6=mysql_query($dia6);
$ejecutar7=mysql_query($dia7);




$sql2 = "INSERT INTO `gym`.`registrodiario` (`idPagoCliente`, `idCliente`, `idTipoPeriodo`, `inicio`, `final`,  `costo`) select idPagoCliente, idCliente, idTipoPeriodo, inicio, final, costo FROM pagosclientes  where idCliente like '%$ID%' AND curdate() < final AND UCASE(DAYNAME(NOW())) = '%$dia5%'   ";
 $ejecutar=mysql_query($sql2);


 if(!$ejecutar){
  echo"no es el dia de hoy que debe venir";

 }else{

    echo"Datos Guardados Correctamente<br><a href='pagos.php'>Volver</a>";
    header("Location:ingresarasistenciadiaria.php");
 }
?>
```

si realizo la consulta solo con esta sentencia, funciona de maravilla pero al añadir (AND UCASE(DAYNAME(NOW())) = '%$dia5%' ) entonces deja de funcionar.

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO `gym`.`registrodiario` (`idPagoCliente`, `idCliente`, `idTipoPeriodo`, `inicio`, `final`,  `costo`) select idPagoCliente, idCliente, idTipoPeriodo, inicio, final, costo FROM pagosclientes  where idCliente like '%$ID%' AND curdate() < final ";
```

SQL
[image: SQL]

consula en sql del dia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es que estás usando marcadores para `LIKE` en una comparación de igualdad, la consulta debería funcionar así: `... final AND UCASE(DAYNAME(NOW())) = '$dia5'` o sea, el marcador `%` es para `LIKE`. Si se trata de una comparación total, no debes usar `LIKE`, que sirve para buscar una parte dentro del contenido.   A lo mejor tampoco necesites `LIKE` para el id: `idCliente like '%$ID%'` si lo que se trata es de filtrar por un valor específico. Usando `LIKE` así, si el valor de `$ID` es por ejemplo `X01`, te traerá todas las filas con IDs como: `ZX01RRR, PPPPPPX01BBBB, LOREMIPSUMX01DOLORSITAMET`

Comment: `$dia5` contiene SQL. ¿Quieres hacer una sub-consulta ó comparar con el valor que regresa esa SQL?. Haz un `var_dump` de `$sql2` y lo verás.

Comment: @Sal Si deseo hacer primero una consulta para que me de el valor de $dia5 y luego otra consulta con la cual comprar el valor de $dia5, hare lo del Var_dump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realice las consultas de la siguiente manera
primero le doy un valor a una variable a partir de un HTML con la función POST

```
    $ID=$_POST['ID'];
```

ya con este dato almacenado puedo realizar la primera consulta

Declaro mi primera consulta ya teniendo el valor del ID

```
$ejecutar2=mysql_query("
   SELECT dia1, dia2, dia3, dia4, dia5, dia5, dia6, dia7
      from pagosclientes where idCliente LIKE '%$ID%'
      AND curdate() < final 
 ");
```

Ejecute la consulta para guardar en campos ej [0], [1]..

```
    $fila2 = mysql_fetch_row($ejecutar2);
```

Ejecuto mi segunda consulta con el resultado de la primera siendo mis campos una busqueda del nombre de mi dia con una busqueda entre el resultado de las variables para esto ocupe operador IN

```
$sql2 = "
   INSERT INTO `gym`.`registrodiario` (`idPagoCliente`, `idCliente`,
          `idTipoPeriodo`, `inicio`, `final`,  `costo`
     ) select idPagoCliente, idCliente, idTipoPeriodo, 
     inicio, final, costo
     FROM pagosclientes  
     where idCliente like '%$ID%' AND curdate() < final 
     AND UCASE(DAYNAME(NOW())) 
     IN ('$fila2[0]', '$fila2[1]','$fila2[2]',
     '$fila2[3]','$fila2[4]', '$fila2[5]','$fila2[6]' )
 ";
```

Answer (score 1):

El error lo tienes precisamente en la línea que comentas:

```
AND UCASE(DAYNAME(NOW())) = '%$dia5%'
```

Cuando uses comodines `%` tienes que usar `LIKE` o, alternativamente, la función `LOCATE`.

Prueba con

```
AND UCASE(DAYNAME(NOW())) LIKE '%$dia5%'
```

Como comentas que sí te funciona con

```
AND UCASE(DAYNAME(NOW())) LIKE 'FRIDAY'
```

y no como te he propuesto, tal vez sea un problema de cómo tienes almacenado el dato en el campo `dia5` de tu tabla `pagosclientes` . Prueba revisando el dato, no vaya a tener algún espacio en blanco, caracteres especiales o cualquier otra cuestión. Hay funciones en PHP que también te pueden ayudar a limpiar el dato:

```
AND UCASE(DAYNAME(NOW())) LIKE '%".strtoupper($dia5)."%'
```

Comment: ya hice el cambio hace rato y pues no funciona

Comment: SI LO PONGO ASI ( $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `gym`.`registrodiario` (`idPagoCliente`, `idCliente`, `idTipoPeriodo`, `inicio`, `final`,  `costo`) select idPagoCliente, idCliente, idTipoPeriodo, inicio, final, costo FROM pagosclientes  where idCliente like '%$ID%' AND curdate() < final AND UCASE(DAYNAME(NOW())) LIKE 'FRIDAY'   "; ) SI FUNCIONA!

Comment: ¿Y necesitas que FRIDAY se obtenga de una variable? ¿O ya lo tienes resuleto?

Comment: Si, por que cada ID tiene campos con dias distintos y sino corresponde al dia de hoy entonces que no se guarde.

Comment: Si a la primera, aún no logro resolverlo.

Comment: ¿Qué guardas en la variable $dia5 que obtiene los datos del campo dia5? ¿FRIDAY u otra cosa?

Comment: si guardo FRIDAY en el campo de la tabla.

Comment: He modificado la respuesta con una posible solución. Por favor, coméntame si ése puede ser el problema y, si no, modifica la pregunta con el SQL de tus tablas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar)

Comment: Buenos Días, probe de la forma que me dijiste, no me funciono, te añadi una imagen de loss datos que estan almacenados en la tabla, solo estoy probando una opción que es el ID = "dadada" , te dejo tambien una imagen de la consulta la cual me da el resultado del dia5 de dadada si la fecha de hoy es menor a la fecha final. en el php al momento de llamar el id ahi si me funciona, pero mandando a solicitar la variable de $dia ahi si que no.

Comment: Utiliza Ctrl+k para añadir código a tu pregunta, no utilices imágenes, que nos obligas a mecanografiar todo ese código para poder hacer las pruebas y nos lleva mucho más tiempo responderte :)

Comment: hola el archivo mysql lo almacene aca https://mega.nz/#!qZdjSQrD!duvF7RlPcg5iru6MS8n8AlZR6UzKZ9qUocH4Yz-L-Oo

Comment: lo intente poner en la pregunta editandola pero lo pondré para que logres verlo

Comment: A mí sí que me funciona, sólo que hoy prueba con `dia6` que ya es SATURDAY :) Eso sí, no tengo ni idea de qué quieres hacer. La base de datos parece bastante bien diseñada (aunque con remiendos), pero este código que nos pasas es muy complicado de entender y da la sensación de que habéis puesto parches a algo con buena pinta... ¿estáis seguros de lo que estáis haciendo?

Comment: Hola @David , gracias por comentar, pues si he probado igual con cada dia de la semana que avanzo y pues tengo los problemas, si lo que sucede es que lo que deseo hacer es insertar los datos en la tabla si el dia de HOY es igual al resultado de la tabla por que es membresia y no todas las membresias tienen permitido todos los dias, me doy a entender?

Comment: en realidad creo que el codigo esta dificil de entender por mi falta de experiencia, comentare el codigo para que sepan que es lo que deseo hacer, gracias @David

Comment: Efectivamente, modifica la pregunta con todo lo que estimes que pueda aportar información para su resolución

Comment: agradezco profundamente los comentarios, la guia que me diste para poder resolver este problema, al final logre hacerlo de la forma siguiente a como veras en la respuesta aceptada. Muchas Gracias!